# Not able to load javascript & css files in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, spring-mvc, webpack

I have created a spring application and it is able to load a jsp page. This jsp includes a html page which has reference to all the javascript & css files. This html along with all js & css files are created by using webpack. Now on running the application , it is not able to find the js & css files , though it is loading the html file

**JSP**

This jsp only include the html page. This `app.html` is created using `webpack`.Where `public` is the folder where `webpack` is storing the generated files. This is configured in `webpack.config.js`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <jsp:include page="../../public/app.html"></jsp:include>
```

I am using webpack `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to create the html page. Below is basic webpack configuration for generating HTML file

```
plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ // Will create a base html file
            title: 'Webpack demo',
            filename: 'app.html', // new file that will be created
            template: './views/index.html', // template file
            inject: 'body' // scripts & css will be included in body
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('app.main.css') // for css
  ]
```

This will create  HTML file and will inject the `css` and `js` files in this html
Also this will take care of the path where these js & css files is located.

Here is the generated HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link href="app.main.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="manifest.02a08507b8282060709c.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.6d74f16c09917449a7c6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.5ea1ec15937cea814094.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

**Problem**

Though the application is able to load the jsp and its included html page but it is not able to refer to the js & css page which is included in the `body` of this html. But when I am directly opening this `app.html` page in browser , it is referring to all the js & css page.

Here are few snapshots for illustration

**Project structure**

[image: Project structure]

**Checking from developers' tool**

[image: Inspecting element to check the files inclusion]

**Files not found error**
[image: Network error file not found]

Comment: Relative URLs for JavaScript and CSS files are relative from the URL of the loading page which is the JSP which is not in the same directory as webpack created files so can't find them. When opening the app.html it loads the JavaScript and CSS files because the relative generated URLs point to them as they are in same directory. The generated URLs need to point from JSP to the folder containing the webpack generated files.

Comment: @Adrian359 how owuld you suggest to approach that problem?